# Save and read checkbox values - many-to-many relationship c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, many-to-many

What is the best way to implement read and save values from tables in many-to-many relationship?
I would like to have checkbox or something like that for selected Technologies.

I have table **Question**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name{ get; set; }
public Country Country { get; set; }
public int? CountryId { get; set; }

public ICollection<Technology> Technologies { get; set; }
```

table **Technology**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name{ get; set; }
public ICollection<Question> Questions{ get; set; }
```

I have created ViewModel **QuestionViewModel** with properties - not sure if necessary

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Technology> Technologies { get; set; } // not sure about this
```

Save works without table Technology.

Maybe I need ViewModel with *ICollection Technologies* and *ICollection Questions* class instead of my current?

Razor page is simple form without Technology class, not sure how to implement that also.
Entity Framework created table **TechnologyQuestions** from code-first approach.

Save action looks like this

```
public ActionResult Save(Question question)
{
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var viewModel = new QuestionViewModel
                {
                    Countries = _context.Countries.ToList()
                };
                return View("NewForm", viewModel);
            }

            if (question.Id == 0)
                _context.Questions.Add(question);
            else
            {
                var questionInDb = _context.Questions.Single(q => q.Id == question.Id);

                questionInDb.Name= question.Name;
                questionInDb.CountryId = question.CountryId;

            }

            _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

I'm using C# MVC 5. Any help or direction appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this.

**QuestionViewModel** has ICollection of Technology class.

In **Save** action I have

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Save(Question question, string[] techIds)
{
   UpdatePostCategories(question, techIds);
   ....
   _context.Questions.Add(question);
   _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And **UpdatePostCategories** method looks like this

```
private void UpdatePostCategories(Question question, string[] techIds)
{
    var selectedCategoriesHS = new HashSet<string>(techIds);
    var postCategories = new HashSet<int>
           (question.Technologies.Select(t=> t.Id));

        foreach (var item in _context.Technologies)
        {
            if (selectedCategoriesHS.Contains(item.Id.ToString()))
            {
                if (!postCategories.Contains(item.Id))
                {
                    question.Technologies.Add(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (postCategories.Contains(item.Id))
                {
                    question.Technologies.Remove(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And in my View checkboxes for all technologies you can select look like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Technologies)
    {
       <div>
         <label>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)</label>
         <input type="checkbox" value="@item.Id" name="techIds" />
       </div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what is not working when you add the table Technology, so I'm assuming your probleme is that EF tries to insert new Technologies when you link them to a question.

You should try attaching the Technology object to the context first:

```
if (question.Id == 0) 
{
    foreach(var tech in question.Technologies)
        _context.Technologies.Attach(tech)
    _context.Questions.Add(question);
}
else
{
    var questionInDb = _context.Questions.Single(q => q.Id == question.Id);

    questionInDb.Name= question.Name;
    questionInDb.CountryId = question.CountryId;

    foreach(var tech in question.Technologies.Where(t => !questionInDb.Technologies.Any(x => x.Id == t.Id)))
        _context.Technologies.Attach(tech);

    //Remove Technologies that have been unchecked in the page
    //...
}
```

Comment: Problem is that I'm not sure in first place how to implement this because it is many-to-may relationship.
Do I need different view model other that the one I already have?

Comment: How to add **Technologies** checkboxes in Razor view? 
Is it ok just to pass **Question** model in _Save_ method?